# React: How to render component children inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, parent-child, children

[Image that TaskContent saved inside array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlKLz.png)

So when I click "Add Task" my TaskContent will be saved on array as a TaskGroup children. But how can I render children inside array?

My App.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddTaskGroup from "./AddTaskGroup";
import TaskGroup from "./TaskGroup";
import Form from "./Form";
import CreateTask from "./CreateTask";
import TaskContent from "./TaskContent";

function App() {

  // Open Form
  const [isFormOpen, setFormIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function addGroupHandler() {
    setFormIsOpen(true);
  }

  function closeGroupHandler() {
    setFormIsOpen(false);
  }

  // Open Task
  const [isFormTaskOpen, setIsOpenTaskOpen] = useState(false);

  function openFormTaskHandler(){
    setIsOpenTaskOpen(true);
  }

  function closedFormTaskHandler(){
    setIsOpenTaskOpen(false);
  }

  // Add Group Task
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

  function createGroupTask(newGroup){
    setGroups(prevGroup => {
      return [...prevGroup, newGroup]
    })
  }

  // Add Task
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]);

  function createTask(newTask){
    setTask(prevTask => {
      return [...prevTask, newTask]
    })
  }




  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <AddTaskGroup onAddGroup={addGroupHandler}/>
      {groups.map((groupItem, index) => {
        return <TaskGroup
        key={index}
        title={groupItem.title}
        onAddTask={openFormTaskHandler}
        >
        {task.map((taskItem, index) => {
          return <TaskContent
          key={index}
          content={taskItem.content}
          />
        })}
        </TaskGroup>
      })}

      <Form onAdd={createGroupTask} openGroup={isFormOpen} onCloseGroup={closeGroupHandler}/>
      <CreateTask addTask={createTask} openFormTask={isFormTaskOpen} onCloseFormTask={closedFormTaskHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My TaskGroup.jsx (parent of TaskContent) this group task shown when click "+" button on the right bottom corner

```
import React from "react";
import TaskContent from "./TaskContent";

function TaskGroup(props) {
  return(
    <div className="taskGroup">
      <div className="titleTaskGroup">
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
      </div>
      <TaskContent taskContent={props.content}/>
      <div className="btnNewTask">
        <button onClick={props.onAddTask}>+</button>
        <p>New Task</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TaskGroup;
```

And TaskContent.jsx (children of TaskGroup) I want this task content shown when I press new task button and will be rendered inside task group

```
[import React from "react";

function TaskContent(props) {
  return(
    <div className="contentTaskGroup">
      <p>{props.taskContent}</p>
      <span>...</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TaskContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TaskGroup.jsx`, you need to change:

```
<TaskContent taskContent={props.content}/>
```

to:

```
{props.children}
```

since you are rendering `TaskContent` in `App.jsx` as children of the `TaskGroup` component. By this way, `TaskGroup` can render the jsx that is passed as `props.children` from its parent component.

After that, in `TaskContent.jsx` you need to change:

```
props.taskContent
```

to:

```
props.content
```

since in `App.jsx` this prop is passed as `content={taskItem.content}`.

Comment: Now my TaskContent have a props <TaskContent/> inside array but still didn't rendered.